# Integrate AWS DynamoDB with Android

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, integration

I have created my AWS account and I want to integrate DynamoDB with my Android app.

I am having a lot of problems lately with integration. I have searched all over the web for the instructions but I didn't get any answers and it is very confusing.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me the steps/instructions to integrate AWS DynamoDB with my android app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [AWS Amplify Framework](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/android).  It's a fantastic tool that can help you get starting building apps on AWS on multiple platforms.  Android is one of the supported platforms, and there are several tutorials to get you started.

Good luck!